# How to get the Response Code Error from $ajax?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I would like to get the code number, like for example the one below:

> (500).

And also go through this error to be able to show the "Code", "requestID" and "message".

Here are some examples of my code and the possible error that may appear to the user.

**CODE EXAMPLE:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var params = {
            // Request parameters
            "visualFeatures": "Categories",
            "details": "{string}",
            "language": "en",
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v1.0/analyze?" + $.param(params),
            beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
                // Request headers
                xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
                xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key","{subscription key}");
            },
            type: "POST",
            // Request body
            data: "{body}",
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            alert("success");
        })
        .fail(function() {
            alert("error");
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Error Code:**

```
Response 500

Possible Errors:

FailedToProcess 
Failed to process the image.
Timeout 
Image processing time out.
InternalServerError 
Internal server error.

application/json
{
        "code":"FailedToProcess",
    "requestId":"B8D802CF-DD8F-4E61-B15C-9E6C5844CCBC",
    "message":"Could not extract image features"
}
```

Comment: try printing `data.status` in the response callback?

Comment: its not your fault, its server issue I mean backend where you request.

Answer (score 0):

The response code can be retrieved like this:

```
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         alert(jqXHR.status);
 })
```

Other properties are also present, you can read about it here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/